# direct.h file not found for ZipArchive

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using [ZipArchive](https://github.com/mattconnolly/ZipArchive), its a new project that I have started and I just imported (added) ZipArchive files to my app.

If I tried to build the app, its throwing me following error.

[image]

> Error: 'direct.h' file not found

What I'm missing? There's no documentation on how to setup ZipArchive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have moved to [SSZipArchive](https://github.com/ZipArchive/ZipArchive) and its good, no need for CocoaPods. As simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you to use CocoaPod to integrate this library on your project so you can avoid problems like the one you described.

You can find ZipArchive here: https://github.com/mattconnolly/ZipArchive